# What is the equivalent tag for <bean:page> in struts 2

Tags: struts2, struts-1, struts-tags

I am working on code migration from Struts 1.x to Struts 2.0

Can anyone please tell me the equivalent tag for the below line in Struts 2.0

```
<bean:page id="req" property="request" /> is the tag in Struts 1.x
```

Now I want to convert the above line in Struts 1.x to the equivalent line in Struts 2.0.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a direct equivalent.

The `<bean:page>` tag just exposes a page-scoped bean for scriptlets, which you shouldn't be using.

Comment: He should also not be migrating to 2.0 :D

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use a `page` scope of the variable you can use scope attribute of the [`s:set`](http://struts.apache.org/release/2.3.x/docs/set.html) tag

```
<s:set var="req" value="#request" scope="page"/>
```

Note, that the `#request` points to the Struts request map, it's not JSP's implicit request object, but it has access to request attributes.